# what is the server for jira-python connection?

Tags: python, jira

I want to create issue on JIRA using python, so I am learning the way on [Welcome to jira-python's documentation](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

But then the first question puzzles me. What is the server if we are using our own JIRA? On this documentation, it uses https://jira.atlassian.com. If I am using JIRA whose url is like: https://bugs.company.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa. What is the server for me?

Now, I am using

```
jira = JIRA(options={'server': 'https://bugs.company.com'})
projects = jira.projects()
keys = [project.key for project in projects]
```

I will get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MethodTest.py", line 9, in <module>
    projects = jira.projects()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 838, in projects
r_json = self._get_json('project')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jira/client.py", line 1423, in _get_json
r_json = json.loads(r.text)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems might comes from the fact that you are using a secure connection to your jira instance. You need to setup a proper certificate for your connection or simply disable certificate verification.

See [jira.client.JIRA](http://jira-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#jira.client.JIRA) options and set `verify` to `False` as such:

```
jira = JIRA(options={'server': 'https://bugs.company.com',
                     'verify': False})
```

Are you setting the proper username and password?

Finally, you might want to check with your IT department for the proper url.